# How to properly plot using map - python 3

Tags: python, plot

I'm trying to plot a bar graph using map in python 3 using this code:

```
tweets=pd.DataFrame()
tweets["text"]=map(lambda tweet:tweet['text'],tweets_data)
#tweets["text"]=list(map(min, tweet:tweet['text'],tweets_data))
tweets["lang"]=map(lambda tweet:tweet['lang'],tweets_data)
tweets["country"]=map(lambda tweet:tweet['place']['country']               
if['place']!=None else None,tweets_data)

tweets_by_lang=tweets['lang'].value_counts()
```

Now I'm getting the error of map returning an object, so I tried the *list(map(min))* but I get a syntax error.. I'm new at python. How can I properly solve this?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add full traceback, follow [mcve] rules.

Comment: You are probably looking for `tweets["text"] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweets_data))`.

Comment: It worked with that syntax, but when I'm trying to apply it to this part of the code:    tweets["country"]=map(lambda tweet:tweet['place']['country']if['place']!=None else None,tweets_data) .  I get this error : _'NoneType' object is not subscriptable_ .   thanks

Comment: You wouldn't want `if['place']`.  Look carefully at your other examples, and figure out what should be between the `if` and the `['place']`.